# How do I install a community/third-party component into my A-Frame scene?

Tags: aframe

I would like to use a component like `shadow` from aframe-extras https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/shadows

How do I use or install external components into my A-Frame scene?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-box color="red" position="0 0 -4"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, published A-Frame components on GitHub follow the same template. In this case, the JS file for the shadow component is at https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/dist/aframe-extras.shadows.js ... in the root `dist/` folder.

To include the JS file externally from our scene, we can just a couple CDN services that allow CORS: `rawgit.com` or `unpkg.com`. Script tag in the `<head>` after aframe

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.shadows.js"></script>
    <!-- or <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras/dist/aframe-extras.shadow.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Then just use the component in your HTML

```
<a-scene>
  <a-box color="red" position="0 0 -4" shadow="cast: true; receive: true"></a-box>
  <a-light shadow-light="cast-shadow: true"></a-light>
</a-scene>
```

So just two steps: add script tag for component, use component.